# How to update 'local State' when Redux State Changes in React Js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

Currently, I am using this approach but I am not sure if this is the correct way

In Component:

Getting Redux State:

```
  const personReduxState = useSelector(({data}) => data.person);
```

Local State:

```
const [locatState,setLocalState]=useState({name:''});
```

In useEffect I am updating the state:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setLocalState({
      name: person?.name
    })
  }, [personReduxState])
```

On First render and whenever the Redux state changes, useEffect runs and update the local state.
Am I doing it right or should I consider another approach?

Comment: Why do you have local state at all? Get rid of `const [locatState,setLocalState]=useState({name:''});` and just use `personReduxState` wherever you intended to use `locatState`

Comment: You already have the state in `personReduxState`, duplicating it with `useState` is going to make your component re-render twice as often and is basically just useless duplication

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to store duplicate of Redux store state, you already got:

```
// this variable got all data, and it will be updated when store will update
const personReduxState = useSelector(({data}) => data.person);

// to get name just write this, and you will get every time latest name from personReduxState
const {name} = personReduxState
```